# Why BugSense is stripping crash stack trace symbols?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, bugsense

I do not see any crash stack trace logs in debug console when running app with enabled BugSense. The only thing I see in debug console is "SIGABRT". I'm enabling Bugsense in AppDelegate didFinishLaunching with the code:

```
[BugSenseController sharedControllerWithBugSenseAPIKey:kBugsenseApiKey userDictionary:nil sendImmediately:YES];
```

Both project and app target build settings "Strip debug symbols during copy" and "Strip linked product" are set to "NO"

If I comment out "[BugSenseController sharedControllerWit..." line then I see full crash stack trace in debug console. Any ideas, what build setting am I missing?

Comment: Are you generating debug symbols?  (What is `Generate Debug Symbols` set to?)

Comment: @devnull "Generate Debug Symbols" are set to YES both in project build settings and target build settings.

Answer (score 0):

in Target build setting set 
Strip Debug Symbols During Copy =YES,
Strip Linked Product=YES

and

```
      - (BOOL) application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {   
              [BugSenseController sharedControllerWithBugSenseAPIKey:@"<Your BugSense API Key>"];

        }
```

then check it

Comment: Nop, that didn't worked out. Did set these two settings both to project build settings and target build settings.

Comment: yes set these two  to project build settings and target build settings.its working fine in my project..nd also..got mail of bug.more  details read doc file.   https://www.bugsense.com/docs/ios